# I disabled Compiz and the title bar on every windows is missing now

Tags: linux-mint, window-manager, compiz, mate-desktop

I am on Linux Mint 15 (Mate). I installed Compiz following the steps in [this tutorial](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1298). Then due to some problems I faced, I decided to disable it. So I executed the following command:

```
metacity --replace
```

Then removed `compiz --replace` from the Startup Applications and reverted `org > mate > desktop > session > required-components > windowmanager` back to `marco`. After logging out and logging in again, I realized that none of my windows have any title bar. What should I do?

[image]

p.s. When I click the `show desktop` icon, the following error appears:

[image]

Comment: @strugee It's almost fixed. I changed `macro` to `marco` in `required-components > windowmanager`. The only problem is that when I login, there is no panel at the bottom of desktop. So I had to create an entry for executing `mate-panel` at startup.

Comment: sounds like a separate question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per a comment discussion below the question, asker thought the window manager was called Macro instead of Marco, and thus got the binary name wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to install the 'CompizConfig Settings Manager', go to the 'effects' page and make sure that the 'Window Decoration' checkbox is checked.

Comment: he said he _disabled_ Compiz. the problem is somewhere else.